# Explicit Ember.run wrapper not required for promise resolution?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, ember-data

Using Ember 1.6.1 with Ember-Data 1.0.0-beta6, while exploring ember-test. I've run into a scenario that unexpectedly runs without issue and I'm looking for some clarity as to why.

Test source:

**test_init.js**

```
/* Other setup... */

App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();
```

**tests.js**

```
test("Visiting route should pull in correct model data", function(){

  /* Mock ajax response with fixture json data containing map:1, place:1, place:2 */

  visit("/maps/1");

  andThen(function(){

    var mapRoute = getMapRoute(); // Helper that retrieves from App.__container__

    mapRoute.store.find("map", mapId).then(function(map){
      equal(map.get("id"), 1);
    });

    mapRoute.store.find("place", 1).then(function(place){
      equal(place.get("id"), 1);
    });

    mapRoute.store.find("place", 2).then(function(place){
      equal(place.get("id"), 2);
    });

  });
});
```

Quoting the [Unit Test Helpers](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/unit-test-helpers/#toc_unit-testing-setup) page:

> The setupForTesting() function call makes ember turn off its automatic
>   run loop execution. This gives us an ability to control the flow of
>   the run loop ourselves, to a degree. Its default behaviour of
>   resolving all promises and completing all async behaviour are
>   suspended to give you a chance to set up state and make assertions in
>   a known state.
>
> `App.setupForTesting();`

Given that auto run loops are disabled with a call to setupForTesting(), I would have expected to have to explicitly create one by wrapping my `store.find` calls in `Ember.run` since promise resolution occurs as part of a runloop's actions queue. However, this test passes just fine.

Is there an implicit runloop here? If so, when is an `Ember.run` wrapper legitimately required (async callbacks external to the Ember API for example)?

Comment: I think use of Ember.run in tests is designed for resolutions of computed properties and observers, rather than promise resolution.

Comment: Isn't the quote from the docs in direct conflict with that? Specifically: `"Its [the runloop] default behavior of resolving all promises and completing all async behaviour..."`. Is the fulfillment of a promise not inherently asynchronous, and therefore the responsibility of the runloop?

Comment: Speaking to bindings.